# Basic Registration using Bootstrap, JQuery, AJAX connecting to JAX-RS and MYSQL

Tags: java

Trying to setup a basic registration as described in the heading above. So to the code. First the bootstrap html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Registration Form using jQuery Ajax and PHP MySQL</title>
<!--This is a CDN link to bootstrap 4 CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--This is a CDN link to the jQuery Library-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--This is a link to a jQuery script to validate form data-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.min.js"></script>
<!--This is a CDN link to bootstrap 4 JS-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--This is a CDN link to bootstrap 4 JS-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--This is a link to custom styles within the project-->
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!--This is a link to the custom JavaScript within the project-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ee309940e2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="signin-form">

    <div class="container small-container">
       <form action="http://localhost:8080/fvah/rest/Customer" class="form-signin" method="post" id="register-form">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <hr />
        <div id="error">
        <!-- error will be shown here ! -->
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name"name="firstNname" id="firstNname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" name="lastName" id="lastNname">
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" name="companyName" id="company">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address1" name="address1" id="address1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address2" name="address2" id="address2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" name="city" id="city">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="County" name="county" id="county">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact No" name="contactNo" id="contactNo">
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="user_email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="ReType Password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword">
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn-save" id="btn-submit">
            <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Create Account
            </button> 
        </div>  

      </form>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then to the jav

```
ascript file


//This JavaScript validates the form data from the user input to prevent unacceptable data or spam getting into the database. The following validations will force the user to enter all the form fields with correct data and allows us to display messages for all errors.
$('document').ready(function()
{ 
     /* validation */
     $("#register-form").validate({
      rules:
      {
            user_name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
            },
            password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            maxlength: 15
            },
            cpassword: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: '#password'
            },
            user_email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
            },
       },
       messages:
       {
            user_name: "Please enter user name",
            password:{
                      required: "Please provide a password",
                      minlength: "Password at least have 8 characters"
                     },
            user_email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            cpassword:{
                        required: "Please retype your password",
                        equalTo: "Password doesn't match !"
                      }
       },
       submitHandler: submitForm    
       });  
       /* validation ends */

//After the validation finishes, the code below Will work without reloading the page and will register a new user by giving them a success message.

       /* form submit */
       function submitForm()
       {        
                var data = $("#register-form").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: 'localhost:8080/fvah/rest/Customer',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: formToJSON(),
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        alert('Customer created successfully');
                        $('#btnDelete').show();
                        $('#cust_id').val(data.id);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert('addCustomer error: ' + textStatus);
                    }
                });
                return false;
        }
       /* form submit */




});
function formToJSON() {
    var cust_id = $('#cust_id').val();
    return JSON.stringify({
        "cust_id": cust_id == "" ? null : cust_id, 
        "firstName": $('#firstName').val(), 
        "lastName": $('#lastName').val(),
        "companyName": $('#companyName').val(),
        "address1": $('#address1').val(),
        "address2": $('#address2').val(),
        "city": $('#city').val(),
        "county": $('#county').val(),
        "contactNo": $('#contactNo').val(),
        "email": $('#email').val(),
        "password": $('#password').val()
        });
}


//We have to combine the validation and form submit code for it to work correctly.
```

Then to the JAX-RS resource and DAO classes

First the DAO
`enter code here`package com.ait.teamproject;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.ait.teamproject.ConnectionHelper;


//import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

public class CustomerDAO {
    public List<Customer> findAll() {
        List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        Connection c = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY firstName";
        try {
            c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
            Statement s = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(processRow(rs));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            ConnectionHelper.close(c);
        }
        return list;
    }
    public List<Customer> findByEmail(String email) {
        List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        Connection c = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers as e " + "WHERE UPPER(email) LIKE ? " + "ORDER BY email";
        try {
            c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, "%" + email.toUpperCase() + "%");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(processRow(rs));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            ConnectionHelper.close(c);
        }
        return list;
    }

    protected Customer processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCust_id(rs.getInt("cust_id"));
        customer.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
        customer.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
        customer.setCompanyName(rs.getString("companyName"));
        customer.setAddress1(rs.getString("address1"));
        customer.setAddress2(rs.getString("address2"));
        customer.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
        customer.setCounty(rs.getString("county"));
        customer.setContactNo(rs.getString("contactNo"));
        customer.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        customer.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        return customer;
    }
     public Customer findById(int id) {
            String sql = "Select * from customers where id=?";
            Customer customer=null;
            Connection c = null;

            try {
                c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setInt(1, id);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    customer= processRow(rs);
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }finally {
                ConnectionHelper.close(c);;
            }
            return customer;
        }

     public List<Customer> findByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {
            List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            Connection c = null;
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM customers as e " +
                    "WHERE UPPER(email) LIKE ? " +
                    "AND UPPER(password) LIKE ? " +
                    "ORDER BY name";
            try {
                c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1,email.toUpperCase());
                ps.setString(2,password.toUpperCase());
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    list.add(processRow(rs));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                ConnectionHelper.close(c);
            }
            return list;
        }

     public List<Customer> findByName(String name) {
            List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            Connection c = null;
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM customers as e where upper(name) like ? order by name";
            try {
                c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, "%" + name.toUpperCase() +"%");
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    list.add(processRow(rs));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                ConnectionHelper.close(c);
            }
            return list;
        }


        public Customer create(Customer customer) {
            Connection c=null;    
            try {
                c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customers (firstName, lastName, companyName, address1, address2, city, county, contactNo, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", new String[] { "ID" });
                ps.setString(1, customer.getFirstName());
                ps.setString(2, customer.getLastName());
                ps.setString(3, customer.getCompanyName());
                ps.setString(4, customer.getAddress1());
                ps.setString(5, customer.getAddress2());
                ps.setString(6, customer.getCity());
                ps.setString(7, customer.getCounty());
                ps.setString(8, customer.getContactNo());
                ps.setString(9, customer.getEmail());
                ps.setString(10, customer.getPassword());
                ps.executeUpdate();
                ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
                rs.next();
                int id= rs.getInt(1);
                customer.setCust_id(id);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                ConnectionHelper.close(c);
            }
            return customer;
        }

        public Customer update(Customer customer) {
            Connection c=null;
            String sql = "UPDATE customers SET firstName=?, lastName=?, companyName=?, address1=?, address2=?, "+
                    "city=?, county=?, contactNo=?, email=?, password=? WHERE id=?";

            try {
                c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);

                ps.setString(1, customer.getFirstName());
                ps.setString(2, customer.getLastName());
                ps.setString(3, customer.getCompanyName());
                ps.setString(4, customer.getAddress1());
                ps.setString(5, customer.getAddress2());
                ps.setString(6, customer.getCity());
                ps.setString(7, customer.getCounty());
                ps.setString(8, customer.getContactNo());
                ps.setString(9, customer.getEmail());
                ps.setString(10, customer.getPassword());
                ps.setInt(11, customer.getCust_id());
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                ConnectionHelper.close(c);
            }
            return customer;
        }


        public boolean remove(int id) {
            Connection c=null;
            String sql = "DELETE from customers where id=?";
            try {
                c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setInt(1,id);
                int count=ps.executeUpdate();
                return count==1;

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                ConnectionHelper.close(c);
            }
        }

}
and the Resource

package com.ait.teamproject;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;



@Path("/Customer")

public class CustomerResource {
    CustomerDAO dao = new CustomerDAO();

    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Customer create(Customer customer) {
        System.out.println("Creating Customer");
        return dao.create(customer);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Customer> findAll() {
        System.out.println("findSomething");
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    @GET @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Customer findById(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        System.out.println("findById " +id);
        return dao.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }

    @GET @Path("search/{query}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Customer> findByName(@PathParam("query") String query) {
        System.out.println("findByName " +query);
        return dao.findByName(query);
    }
    @GET @Path("/query")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Customer> findByTrainerAndJockey(
            @QueryParam("email") String email,
            @QueryParam("password") String password) {
        System.out.println("findByEmailAndPassword: " +email+password);
        return dao.findByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    }


    @PUT @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Customer update(Customer customer) {
        System.out.println("Updating Customer: "+ customer.getFirstName());
        dao.update(customer);
        return customer;
    }

    @DELETE @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        dao.remove(id);
    }

}

and the MYSQL file
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;

CREATE TABLE customers (
    cust_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    firstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    companyName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    address1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    address2 VARCHAR(20),
    city VARCHAR(20),
    county VARCHAR(20),
    contactNo VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(cust_id) ); 



  Unfortunately the POST command in the script.js is being seen as a GET command by the CustomerResource java file and insertion obviously does not happen in the database. Any help would be most appreciated. When I complete the registration form and try and create the user, it does use the script.js and I I have a system out print in the customer resource file so I can see that the customerresource.java class is being accessed. What is strange though is that the AJAX POST command for some reason is being misinterpreted as an AJAX GET with the Resource class and I simply do not understand why this might be.
```

If there are further details I can provide I will be happy to do so. This is the initial stages of a school project and its a huge learning curve for all involved as none of us have covered these technologies in the past.